# request.getHeader("referer") returns NULL - Beginner

Tags: http, grails, groovy

`request.getHeader("referer")` returns null after I redirect the page. Why it happens? And how can I get the referer ?

```
redirect(action: "pageUnion", params: [param1: 'something'])
            println("> "+request.getHeader("referer"))
```

Comment: Why would you do that in a controller after invoking `redirect`?

Comment: No, i actually did that check in the `Filter`, but i just tried it in the controller to check if its working. It gives the same result here as well

Comment: Anyone knows how to sort this ?

Comment: I think you should move and rewrite `println("> "+request.getHeader("referer"))` in the corresponding Test

Answer (score 2):

In general that does work. There isn't enough context in your question to know why it isn't working for you but there are a number of scenarios for which the referer is expected to be null. For example, if the user didn't click on a link but instead typed the URL into their browser or used a bookmark. If the user types a url into the browser and sends the request and that results in a redirect, I would expect referer to be null for the initial action as well as the one redirected to.

Comment: I am using sms to send link to user. Is there any way for me to get referer in the header?